# Microsoft Azure cdn vs media streaming services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-cdn

So, I'm working on an application where admins will be able to upload videos, for others to view on different platforms (mobile devices, computers etc). It is to be hosted on Azure, and I'm having a bit difficulty figuring out if I need to use Media services or simply a CDN.

When does it make sense to use the Media services over simply uploading to a blob and viewing through CDN? What are the advantages of using one over another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Azure CDN pulls content from Azure Media Services streaming server, so you could stream your content from the edge. You don't have to use a CDN if you don't need to deliver content in a large scale at a time. Rather, you could directly streaming content from streaming server offered by Azure Media Services.

The reason you maybe confused is because there are CDN vendors in the market (such as Akamai) offers streaming server capability. But by CDN itself, the edge network was just for caching the bits, not acting like a streaming server.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan